# Calculate : $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax^2}e^{i\omega x}\cos(bx)dx $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-integration

How I calculate this integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax^2}e^{i\omega x}\cos(bx)dx$$

where $a, b, \omega$ are constant.

Comment: $a > 0$. It reduces to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a(x^2 + 2cx)}$ where $2ac= -i\omega\pm ib$. Then assume $c$ is real, use that $x^2 + 2cx = (x+c)^2-c^2$ and change of variable $y= a(x+c)$ to make the Gauss integral appear. The obtained equality stays true for $c \in \mathbb{C}$ by analytic continuation.

Answer (score 2):

As reuns commented, consider 
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax^2}e^{i\omega x}\cos(bx)\,dx$$
$$J=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax^2}e^{i\omega x}\sin(bx)\,dx$$
$$K=I+iJ=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax^2}e^{i\omega x}e^{ibx}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(ax^2-i(\omega+b) x)}\,dx$$
$$L=I-iJ=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax^2}e^{i\omega x}e^{-ibx}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(ax^2-i(\omega-b) x)}\,dx$$ Now, for each $K,L$ integrals, complete the square and you will arrive to some gaussian integral eaxy to evaluate. Finally, $I=\frac 12(K+L)$.